# Why iframe inside an iframe can't do window.top.addEventListener?

Tags: javascript, html, iframe, cross-domain

I have an iframe application which register event listener like this (this iframe is inserted on another domain):

```
<iframe src="example.com/test" onload="window.top.addEventListener('message', (event) => {
    const data = {
        url: window.location.origin
    };
    event.source.postMessage(JSON.stringify(data), event.origin);
});
"/>
```

But if I add second iframe my message is not sent:

```
<iframe src="example.com/main">
    <iframe src="example.com/test" onload="window.top.addEventListener('message', (event) => {
        const data = {
            url: window.location.origin
        };
        event.source.postMessage(JSON.stringify(data), event.origin);
    });
    "/> 
</iframe>
```

In second case I get

**VM2818:2 Uncaught DOMException: Blocked a frame with origin "example.com" from accessing a cross-origin frame.**

I need this functionality to detect where my iframe is hosted (on which website).

What is causing this error? How may I fix it?

Thanks!

Comment: You can't, see https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Security/Same-origin_policy

Comment: @Teemu why it works for me in first example? onload callback in first example is executed in context of another domain, not mine example.com? and in second example onload callback is executed in example.com context because it is placed inside an another iframe?